# Dictionary entry and derived forms, were they equal at some point?

Tags: grammar, meaning, potential-form, causation

I will first state the dictionary entry, and then other formations that also yield the dictionary entry.

Consider the following :

1. 思える　- to seem/appear,

   - potential form of 思う - can think
2. 合わせる　- to join together,

   - potential form of 合わす - can join together
   - causative form of 合う - to let suit/match/agree with
3. 解ける - to come untied / be solved

   - potential form of 解く - can untie/solve
4. 空ける - to empty

   - potential form of 空く - can become empty

As above, there are words that in their potential/causative form that already have a dictionary meaning that is different from their conjugated forms.

**(Question)** Were they equal in meaning at some point in time? Or are they completely different words and should be treated as such?

Answer (score 1):

Not all of what you claim as potential form are potential forms. Actually, all `-e-` except for the one in `思える` just switch transitivity.

You seem to be doing the conjugation wrong. Notice that when the verb stem ends with a vowel, the potential affix is `-re-` instead of `-e`, which is only for when the verb stem ends with a consonant.

> omow-u → omou (tr.) 'think'
> omow-**e**-ru → omoeru (tr. potential) 'can think'
>
> aw-u → au (it.) 'meet'
> aw-**e**-ru → aeru (it. potential) 'can meet'
>
> aw-ase-ru (tr.) 'meet'
> aw-ase-**re**-ru (tr. potential) 'can meet'
>
> tok-u (tr.) 'solve'
> tok-**e**-ru (tr. potential) 'can solve'
>
> tok-e-ru (it.) 'dissolve'
> tok-e-**re**-ru (it. potential) 'can dissolve'
>
> ak-u (it.) 'open'
> × ak-**e**-ru (it.) 'can open'
>
> ak-e-ru (tr.) 'open'
> ak-e-**re**-ru (tr. potential) 'can open'

Comment: Does that mean some verbs don't have a potential form?

Comment: But isn't the formation of short-potential form for 五段 verbs their 連用形＋[得]{え}る with sound contraction? E.g. 解く > 解き+得る > 解ける. This means that given any 五段 verb, we can form a potential form for it right?

Comment: @Flaw `解ける` is actually ambiguous between intransitivized form and potential form. And, it has the meaning that you expect. `解く` 'solve' vs. `解ける` 'can solved'.

Comment: @Flaw There is no contraction. 'tok + e + ru > tokeru'

Comment: @sawa I'm not familiar with the "k" left hanging in "tok". To me only these few can exist - とか,　とき,　とく,　とけ and　とこ. So と+K+え+る seems odd to me.

Comment: @Flaw Your claim that the potential `-e-` affix comes from `得る` is interesting. Is it your original, or did learn from someone? If this is true, the `r` in the `-re-` form used after a vowel-ending verb will be an epenthetic consonant to avoid hiatus.

Comment: @Flaw `k` is not hanging. `tok` is the stem. The negative form of `解く` is `解かない` `tok-anai`, which shows that the stem is `tok`. It is a vowel-ending verb, or in traditional terms, it is a godan verb.

Comment: @sawa for reference, I learned my conjugation schemes here: http://grammar.nihongoresources.com/doku.php?id=conjugation

Comment: @Flaw Thanks for the reference. I just saw it. The idea is suggestive, but it is cheating. Under the godan verbs:short potential:informal, you can see it saying `連用形 + 得る`. But with formal, it suddenly stops mentioning `得る`, and says `連用形 + えます`, so that when it comes to ichidan verbs, which does not have the informal form, it does not need to explain how `得る` would be related to `未然形 + られます`.

Comment: @Louis Yes. I cannot think of the potential form of the intransitive verb `開く` (not that of the transitive verb `開ける`).

Comment: @sawa: You seem to be advocating ら抜き...?

Comment: @ZhenLin I am not particularly for or against it, but it is an already established form, and the webpage that Flaw links mentions this form as informal potential form.

Comment: @sawa "I cannot think of ..." <- this seems to be a perception problem.  I know that some French verbs do not have complete conjugations, but I never heard that about Japanese.  I see nothing wrong with 開ける being potential form of 開く (I'm discussing grammar validity, not usage).

Comment: @Axioplase Are you thinking about 'hirakeru'? That is possible. What I mentioned is 'akeru' as a potential verb. Actually, it was my type mistake. I originally meant to type that I cannot think of the potential form of `空ける`.